# VMware - client isolation

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware

How do I create VMs using VMWare Workstation that are connected to the internet but isolated from each other?

These are the characteristics of these VMs:

- From the internet, the VMs appear to be using the host IP address (like using NAT)
- The VMs are unable to communicate with each other
- The VMs are able to communicate with the Internet (like in NAT/Bridged mode)

I am currently using VMWare Workstation. It would be better if there is no need to configure anything within the Guest VMs themselves.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to accomplish this is to go to Edit -> Virtual Network Editor, and create X virtual networks with different subnets for each.. i.e. 192.168.101.0, 192.168.102.1.. and so on. In the VMet information section, leave it on bridged, and in the drop down box.

Next, when a virtual machine is running or powered off (not suspended), right-click on its tab and go to settings, network, and under the 'Custom' drop box select a virtual network that has yet to be used.

[image]